# Shared folders and Dropbox /delta

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to detect changes in a user's dropbox account using /delta. All shared folders content changes don't show up. If I specifically call them using /metadata it shows the contents, but not with delta. I couldn't find any information specifying that shared folders changes are not supported.

Also, somewhat related to this, would Dropbox send me notifications of any events that have changed in shared folders?

Comment: Shared folder contents should definitely be returned via `/delta`. If you're sure you're seeing something different, please open an API support ticket so we can investigate: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact. As for getting notifications, `longpoll_delta` or webhooks should do what you want.

Comment: All I get is the folder name, none of the files. Even when using no cursor.

Comment: Did you open a support ticket?

Comment: Yes, I realized that for shared folders, it's returning has_more as true.